# ng-class conditional update conditions array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Say I have an array:

```
$scope.selected = [...]
```

In my template:

```
<div ng-click="toggle(rhino)" id="rhino-{{ rhino.id }}" ng-repeat="rhino in rhinos" ng-if="rhino.species=='black-rhino'" ng-model="rhino.id" class="center selectable" ng-class="(selected.indexOf(rhino.id) > -1) ? 'selected-icon' : 'selected-icon-disabled'">
        <img width="100px" src="{{ rhino.face }}">
      </div>
```

This changes the CSS style if the image is clicked, by adding the object if to an array, and of the object id is in the array, the style gets changed as in the code.

But if I clear the array with a button in the navbar with he same controller:

```
$scope.selected = [];
```

I was under the impression that then the class will also change, but it stays the same.

How should I do this?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle ?

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, see https://jsfiddle.net/2x3072hq/1/. Click the first div to clear the array. Your problem might be you're clearing the array outside of a $apply call.

Comment: I realised my problem is that the reset button is part of the nav-bar-buttons, I give it the same controller as the controller with the template. So Im guessing its to do with thast that its not resetting. Reset is a seperate button on the navbar